# Python nested loops with if statements: Replacing values inside a range

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, nested-loops

**Question**

Given a range from 0 to 30, output all the integers inside the range with the following requirements:

I. Replace all the numbers that aren't divisible by 3 with **Asterisk symbol(*)**;

II. Replace all the numbers inside `range(10, 15)` and `range(20, 25)` with **Underscores(_)**.

**Sample Output**

> 0 * * 3 * * 6 * * 9 _ _ _ _ _ _ * * 18 * _ _ _ _ _ _ * 27 * * 30

**My Codes:**

```
range1 = range(10, 16)
range2 = range(20, 26)
for i in range(0, 31):
    while i not in range1 or range2:
        if i % 3 == 0:
            print(i, end = " ")
            break
        elif i % 3 != 0:
            print('*', end = " ")
            break
    else:
        print('_', end = " ")
```

**My Output:**

0 * * 3 * * 6 * * 9 * * 12 * * 15 * * 18 * * 21 * * 24 * * 27 * * 30

I am struggling with my codes since I've tried many times my codes failed to replace the numbers inside both ranges, it always skips the range check and outputs `*`. Any helpful ideas are appreciated, I hope I can improve my logic mindset instead of just getting the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can't use `i not in range1 or range2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true), I suggest to use set union for efficiency. Also the `while` loop is useless, a simple test is sufficient.

***NB. trying to keep an answer as close as possible to your original code here.***

```
ranges = set(range(10, 16)) | set(range(20, 26))

for i in range(0, 31):
    if i not in ranges:
        if i % 3 == 0:
            print(i, end = " ")
        elif i % 3 != 0:
            print('*', end = " ")
    else:
        print('_', end = " ")
```

output: `0 * * 3 * * 6 * * 9 _ _ _ _ _ _ * * 18 * _ _ _ _ _ _ * 27 * * 30`

`ranges`: `{10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25}`

Comment: Thank you for the quick comment, any methods besides the ```set``` function? Because it's beyond my current studying content.

Comment: You can use `ranges = list(range(10, 16)) + list(range(20, 26))` instead, this gives you a list, less efficient but it will work ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's so easy and simple to do it without extra ranges:

```py
for i in range(0, 31):
    if (10 <= i <= 16) or (20 <= i <= 26):
        print('_', end=' ')
    elif i % 3 != 0:
        print('*', end=' ')
    else:
        print(i, end=' ')
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very close to my current knowledge.

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck in your studies!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `range`, use a simpler and more efficient syntax of [chained comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) instead. Simplify your `if` condition as well: there is no need to check twice whether the number is divisible by 3. Skip `break` too. Separate creation of the list using `append` and printing of the list, which you do **after** the list is created (creation of the data and its printing are best kept separate).

```
lst = []
for i in range(31):
    if 10 <= i <= 15 or 20 <= i <= 25:
        lst.append('_')
    elif i % 3:
        lst.append('*')
    else:
        lst.append(i)

print(' '.join(str(x) for x in lst))
# 0 * * 3 * * 6 * * 9 _ _ _ _ _ _ * * 18 * _ _ _ _ _ _ * 27 * * 30

# You can also use a simpler `print` to give the same result, 
# as suggested by *QwertYou*:
print(*lst)
```

Comment: `print(*lst)` looks less bulky